# Can i still install service pack 1 on win7, if my win7 is activated and has ultimate edition?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I run win7 , 64bit OS.
I want to install .net framework 4.5\4.6, but it asks me to install sp1 first.
the edition is ultimate. I need to install sp1 , can i do it?

Comment: Yeah, why wouldn't it be possible? service packs are packs with windows updates. It is not tied to your version being ultimate.

Comment: what does version of windows have to do with service packs? -1

Comment: Nothing really. Just use windows update to install service pack 1. You should probably have done this a long time ago. If you are having problem updating for some reason, check out : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1

Comment: **Don't turn off automatic updates.** Your system needs them to be stable and secure.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k, yes  i did install it, no problem ! i had ultimate edition, and sp1 installed just nicely! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there certainly shouldn't be any reason that you can't do that.

Personally, when it comes to large updates like a Windows service pack install I prefer to download the full installation file and install it manually (versus Windows Update).  You can download the `windows6.1-KB976932-X64` file from here:

[Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB976932)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)

Comment: sp1 installed fine on ultimate edition win 7 , thx you all